# Getting Strange Segmentation Fault In Code

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Im getting a strange segmentation fault. I almost ignored it for it only appeared when the strings that were passed to the function begin with the letter v or greater. The program consists of an array of 26 linked list pointers and a function that creates a new node, sorts them (using another function and then adds them to the array of linked lists). Heres the code where the segmentation fault is experienced.

```
 void sort(contact* newContact,int ind, contact** array[]){

    contact* current; //pointer to current contact

    //Case to test if the contact belongs at the head ###SEGMENTATION FAULT IF name begins with 'v'
    if ((*array)[ind] == NULL || strcmp(&(*array)[ind]->name[0],&newContact->name[0])>0){

        newContact->next=(*array)[ind]; // contect next pointer is equal to the pointer at index 'ind'

       (*array)[ind]=newContact; //goes to array and change the pointer at the index 'ind'   
    }

    else{

        current=(*array)[ind]; //updates the current pointer to the first pointer in the index 'ind'

        //finds the position to insert contact
        while(current->next!=NULL&&strcmp(&current->next->name[0],&newContact->name[0])<0){

            current=current->next; //updates pointer if current is not NULL or current is smaller than new contact
        }

        //the loop will break at the insertion point. 
        //inserts contact
        newContact->next=current->next;
        current->next=newContact;



   }

    printf("ADDED\n");
    }
```

And here is the code that creates the node, along with the code that collects the input in the case it goes wrong somewhere

```
void addContact(contact* list[]){
contact* new= malloc(sizeof(contact)); // creates new contact and allocates memory for it

printf("NAME: ");
new->name=GetInput(1); //saves the name
printf("NUMBER: ");
new->number=GetInput(0); //saves the number

int x=GetIndex(new->name);
contact** ptr=&list[x];
sort(new,x, &ptr);

printf("Contact Added!\n");
}
```

For this function, if the type is 1, it ensures the string entered begins with an alphabetical character. If not, it is left alone

```
char* GetInput(int type){
int loop=0;
char* buffer; //stores the entire input from the user 

if (type==1){

    do {
        scanf("%ms",&buffer); //takes input from user

        //checks if alphabetical
        if (isalpha(buffer[0]))
            loop=1;

        else{
            printf("Try again\nThe first character must be alphabetical\n");
            free(buffer);
        }
    }
    while(loop==0);    
}

//when 1 isnt specified, the input is left untreated
else{
    scanf("%ms",&buffer);
}

return buffer;

}
```

Comment: Segmentation fault is run time error so Try to do "gdb" at least you will come to know exactly at which lines segmentation fault occurs. After that you can easily solve it.

Comment: I did run in gdb, thats why i could pinpoint in the code where the segmentation fault is, but i cant understand how it only gets the segmentation fault when the name[0] character is v or greater. It works perfectly with the other letters except the letters from v-z

Comment: To begin with, your `GetInput` function is **completely** wrong!!! 1. You are not initializing the `buffer` variable, so it is most likely pointing to an invalid memory address. 2. What exactly you're trying to achieve in the `do/while` loop remains a mystery (checking that the first character is alphabetic??? What about the other characters?). 3. If you want to scan a string of characters from the user, then you should call `scanf` with **the value** of `buffer`, and not with **the address** of `buffer`...

Comment: You've declared `array` as `contact ***`, but you're treating it as though it had been declared `contact **(*)[N]`.  That's going to cause heartburn.  You need to step back and make sure all your types sync up.

Comment: @barakmanos scanf is going to initialize the buffer pointer. Using the %ms specifier, scanf will malloc data. I was trying to check if the first character entered is alphabetical before proceeding.

Comment: @JohnBode the (*) goes to the array allowing the index in the array to be specified. Im not sure how to make it any better though, the pointers are starting to confuse me. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has a lot of problems.  The first thing you need to do is to crank up the warning settings on your compiler as high as they'll go.  There's a lot of stuff here that isn't a *syntax* error, but is still a mistake.

One major problem (and I suspect the source of your runtime errors) is in `getInput`:

```
char* GetInput(int type){
int loop=0;
char* buffer; //stores the entire input from the user
```

No.  All `buffer` stores is a single pointer value; you haven't actually set aside any
storage for the input.  `buffer` doesn't point anywhere meaningful.  Since it's declared `auto` and you don't explicitly initialize it, `buffer` will initially contain a random bit pattern that may correspond to a writable address, a protected address, or a *trap representation*; that is, a bit pattern that cannot be a valid pointer value.

Attempting to write through an invalid pointer value will invoke *undefined behavior*, which simply means the compiler isn't required to handle the coding error in any particular way.  It may issue a diagnostic and halt translation, issue a diagnostic and continue translation, or ignore the problem completely.  If it completes translation and produces a binary, that binary may crash immediately, or it may limp along in a bad state until something else causes it to crash later on, or it may appear to function normally.

However, you've cleverly sidestepped the whole issue as follows:

```
if (type==1){

    do {
        scanf("%ms",&buffer); //takes input from user
                    ^^^^^^^
```

Instead of passing `buffer` as your argument (like you should), you pass `&buffer`.  Unlike `buffer`, `&buffer` *is* a valid pointer (it's the address of the `buffer` variable), so you're not trying to write through an invalid pointer.  Unfortunately, `&buffer` has the wrong *type* - `char **` instead of `char *`.  Your compiler *should* have warned you about this; if it didn't, raise the warning level (also, `m` is not a valid modifier for the `%s` conversion specifier AFAIK; what is it supposed to do?).

Problem is, the `buffer` variable is only large enough to store a single `char *` value (anywhere from 2 to 4 to 8 bytes wide, depending on the platform); so if `char *` on your platform is 4 bytes wide, you could store a string of up to 3 characters plus the terminating 0 character, and nothing "bad" would happen (that is, you wouldn't overwrite memory belonging to a different object).  Anything longer and you risk clobbering something important (likely leading to the "limp along in a bad state until something else causes a crash later" outcome).

Here's one way, if not necessarily the *best* way, to fix that code (reformatting to make it easier on my rapidly aging eyes; obviously, formatting is largely a matter of taste, so you can reformat this to however you like):

```
#define FIXED_BUFFER_LEN 20 // Initial buffer size; make this large enough to
                            // handle most of your expected inputs

char* GetInput( int type )
{
  int loop = 1; // yes, I'm changing the sense of this test

  /**
   * Create a local, temporary buffer for input, large enough to handle
   * most expected inputs
   */
  char tempBuffer[FIXED_BUFFER_LEN + 1];

  /**
   * Output buffer pointer, initialized to a known *invalid* value
   */
  char* buffer = NULL;

  /**
   * Build a format string for our scanf statements; a %s without a 
   * maximum length specifier is a gaping security hole.
   */
  char fmt[15]; // stores a string of the form "%DDD...s", where DDD... is 
                //the field width specifier; for example, "%20s"

  /**
   * Honestly, you want to check the result of the following operation,
   * but I've already spent more time on this than I expected.
   */
  sprintf( fmt, "%%%ds", FIXED_BUFFER_LEN );

  if (type==1)
  {
    do 
    {
      scanf( fmt, tempBuffer ); //takes input from user

      //checks if alphabetical
      if ( isalpha( tempBuffer[0] ))
        loop=0;

      else
      {
        printf( "Try again\nThe first character must be alphabetical\n" );
      }
  }
  while( loop );    
}

//when 1 isnt specified, the input is left untreated
else
{
  scanf( fmt, tempBuffer );
}

/**
 * Only now, after we've validated our input, do we allocate the 
 * dynamic memory for the buffer. 
 */ 
buffer = calloc( strlen( tempBuffer ) + 1, sizeof *buffer );
if ( buffer )
  strcpy( buffer, tempBuffer );

return buffer;
```

}

There are still some problems with this code (`scanf` has *many* issues), but this should get you moving in the right direction.  Turn up the warning settings on your compiler as high as they will go, and analyze and repair every one of them.

Comment: Alright, i havent read through the entire thing. I get what you're saying so far. The %ms or %as (it was specified as m in one manual and a in another manual) specifier makes scanf automatically allocate enough memory to store the incoming string and returns the address to the corresponding variable of the specifier, which should be the address of a char*, so it can store the string pointer to the char* specified. Also, how can I crank up my warning settings? I usually use Werror and Wall when compiling.
Also, is it an issue comparing the characters of strings created with malloc?

Comment: also, sorry for taking up so much of your time

Comment: You may want to get into the habit of compiling with `-std=c99`, too. `%m` is supported by POSIX, but it's not ISO C, and with `scanf()` having all the issues it does in the first place, having it do this as well seems like a bit of a misfeature to me, but others may have different opinions.

Comment: Wow, I often thought of the %m specifier as gold since I wouldn't have to worry about malloc'ing memory

Comment: @AJPennster: Interesting, I didn't know about the `m` modifier for `%s` (it's not standard), which basically throws everything I said out the window.  Never mind.

Comment: Actually, my issue was the input. I fixed it, decided to limit the size of the string received.